# using Math.pow combinations on an array for 1% relative error

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I was wondering about how you access and calculate values from a single array that must be accessed by multiple variables. The situation is your given an array of type double with these elements...              -5.0, -4.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1, -1 / 2, -1 / 3,
                -1 / 4, 0, 1 / 4, 1 / 3, 1 / 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
and the goal is to use this with the Math.pow() function to do a sequence of calculations on w,x,y, and z until a combination of these calculations are within 1% relative error to the original number entered. An example is user enters 3.14 for starting value then they enter 4 positive numbers that are not equal to 1 for values w,x,y, and z. The goal is raise w,x,y, and z to powers using the Math.pow() function with the exponent being elements of the powerArray. These powers must change inside a while loop and later a for loop until the product of w,x,y, and z raised to a certain combination of the elements of the powerArray are within 1% relative error to the original 3.14. My issue is figuring out how in a while loop how to access this powerArray and be able to have the indexes change while accessing the array on variables w,x,y, and z until there product of these powers are within the 1% relative error of the original number. Please help :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
double epilson, valueW, valueX, valueY, valueZ;
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0;
double approx = 0;
boolean checkValue = true;
double[] powerArray = { -5.0, -4.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1, -1 / 2, -1 / 3,
        -1 / 4, 0, 1 / 4, 1 / 3, 1 / 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };


System.out.print("Enter a value for epilson u: ");
epilson = keyboard.nextDouble();
while (checkValue) {
    System.out.print("Enter value for w: ");
    valueW = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter value for x: ");
    valueX = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter value for y: ");
    valueY = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter value for z: ");
    valueZ = keyboard.nextDouble();

    if ((valueW == 1) || (valueX == 1) || (valueY == 1)
            || (valueZ == 1)) {
        System.out.println("Values of w,x,y,z must not be equal to 1.");

    } else {

        boolean iterator = true;
        while (iterator) {

            if (approx >= (epilson * 0.01)) {
                iterator = false;
            } else {
                approx = Math.pow(valueW, powerArray[i])
                        * Math.pow(valueX, powerArray[j])
                        * Math.pow(valueY, powerArray[k])
                        * Math.pow(valueZ, powerArray[l]);
                i++;
                j++;
                k++;
                l++;
            }

        }

    }
    System.out.print("The exponents that bring value closer to Epilson are "
            + powerArray[i] + ", " + powerArray[j] + ", "
            + powerArray[k] + ", " + powerArray[l]);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The final value is " + approx
            + " which is within 0.1% of " + epilson);
    checkValue = false;
}
```

}

so far nothing is working an a test case yields the following...
    `Enter a value for epilson u: 3.14`
    `Enter value for w: 13`
    `Enter value for x: 5`
    `Enter value for y: 200`
    `Enter value for z: 99`
    `The exponents that bring value closer to Epilson are -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0 The final value is 0.0 which is within 0.1% of 3.14`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have time to carefully review the code but. You can do your calculations one time outside the `while` loop and store it a variable `x`. Then loop until that value is not what you want:

i.e

```
while( x > someOtherValue)
    // do something
```

inside the loop repeat what you do outside and update and `x` variable. Then after the loop put what you want to do when `x` is actually holding an acceptable value.

Comment: please take a look when you can. Most I got so far is four while loops